# IllegalMutationException from Beam PTransform

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

This is the Apache Beam PTransform that I wrote:

```
public class NormalizeTransform
  extends PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<SimpleTable>> {

@Override
public PCollection<SimpleTable> expand(PCollection<String> lines) {
  ExtractFields extract_i = new ExtractFields();
  PCollection<SimpleTable> table = lines
    .apply("Extracting data model fields from lines",
           ParDo.of(extract_i));
}                                                   

public class ExtractFields extends DoFn<String, SimpleTable> {

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
  try {
    String line = c.element();              
    // fill table
    for (Table_Struct st: this.struct){
      String o = line.substring(st.pos_1, st.pos_2));
      this.table.getClass().getField(st.Field_Name).set(
        this.table, o);                                                                     
    }
    c.output(this.table);
  }
}
```

and sporadically I will get the following error `IllegalMutationException`, which means I repeated the running of the code, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.IllegalMutationException: PTransform Transform/Extracting data model fields from lines/ParMultiDo(ExtractFields) mutated value  after it was output (new value was ). Values must not be mutated in any way after being output.

at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory$ImmutabilityEnforcingBundle.commit(ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory.java:135)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.EvaluationContext.commitBundles(EvaluationContext.java:214)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.EvaluationContext.handleResult(EvaluationContext.java:163)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ExecutorServiceParallelExecutor$TimerIterableCompletionCallback.handleResult(ExecutorServiceParallelExecutor.java:268)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.finishBundle(TransformExecutor.java:168)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.run(TransformExecutor.java:109)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't think I specifically changed any output of the value anywhere in my codes.  The MutationDetectors will compare two values: previousValue and newValue. In my case, the previousValue is usually one input value and the newValue is another input value. How come the Transform will try using one input value to modify another input value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where `this.table` is coming from.

But to help you understand the error message, keep in mind that `processElement` may be called on multiple inputs. The first call will output `this.table`. The next call will mutate `this.table` before outputting it.

If this mutation happens after the first call has output `this.table` and before downstream code has had the chance to read `this.table`, you will have incorrect results. So, this error is indicating that you have mutated the content of `this.table` after the reference was output -- something you should not do.

Consider instead either (1) outputting a copy of `this.table` or (2) creating the table as a local field. For example:

```
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
  try {
    String line = c.element(); 
    Table table = /* create the table */;             
    // fill table
    for (Table_Struct st: this.struct){
      String o = line.substring(st.pos_1, st.pos_2));
      this.table.getClass().getField(st.Field_Name)
        .set(table, o);                                                                     
    }
    c.output(table);
  }
}
```

Also note that performing reflection within each `processElement` may be slower than desired. If you can modify the fields directly, that will likely be better.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. That explains why. Actually I do have a concern over the reflection within `processElement` that may drag performance. But in this case, table is runtime defined and can't be modified directly, and hence I resort to using reflection. Do you have a better idea than refection?

Comment: Given it is defined at runtime, it doesn't sound like you have many options other than reflection. It would depend on what other options / libraries you could use to avoid reflection.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on other options/libraries? thanks @Ben Chambers

Comment: Other options would be things like using AutoValue, Avro or Protocol Buffers to generate code from a schema, and using those. A lot depends on what your actual use cases are. You may want to ask describe what you're trying to do in more detail and ask a more general Java question.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that the enforcement compares deserialized values, so it assumes that the deserialization is deterministic. If the object contains collections, this can require attention to the order of the elements.